# How to create a multi step form that can be saved/edited by multiple users?

Tags: forms

I need some tips on how to implement a form with these specifications:

- Multi steps. for example the user completes section 1 then clicks next to go to section 2 and so on (can be tabs or anything similar).
- It can be saved, so users can come back to continue also multiple users can edit
- Some users can add a new form to the site (with a different title for a new set of users)
- Users should have different permission levels to interact with these forms (creator, editor or view only).

I've been looking at webform. But it doesn't seem to offer what I need. Because it doesn't use native Drupal fields. I need a form that stores data in Drupal standard format. This allows me to expand my form's capabilities (For example using views).
Are there any combination of modules that can be helpful here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Multistep](https://www.drupal.org/project/multistep) module adds multiple-step functionality to CCK forms. It does so by assigning a step number to each fieldgroup within the content type and hiding all the groups that do not belong to the current step. The user can then use different submitting buttons that will redirect to the previous, next, or current step.

For further reference look into this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/529976).

Comment: By using this module, you can use the fields of form in the views.

Answer (score 0):

With Webforms, it is possible to create forms that span more than one page. These forms are known as multistep, or multipage forms. and also with expected features.

ref link: [Creating multistep webforms](https://www.drupal.org/node/324779)

Comment: thanks, I forgot to mention why webform is not a good candidate for me. Webform doesn't use native drupal fields so we can't use it in views or expand it with many other modules.

Answer (score 0):

[Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) supports:

- multistep forms
- allowing who can submit the form (under form settings)
- choosing to allow users to "save" the state of the form

[image]

The create/edit/view permissions can be controlled with Drupal's core permissions scheme.

Who has access to which webform will have to be configured using other content access modules (check the screenshot).

Comment: thanks, I forgot to mention why webform is not a good candidate for me. Webform doesn't use native drupal fields so we can't use it in views or expand it with many other modules.